# Scan for cellular networks

Tags: android

I want to get a list of the cellular networks in range, and I want to refresh it from time to time.

In Android API 28, a method `TelephonyManager.requestNetworkScan(...)` is added. Unfortunately, I cannot set the minimum API to `28` in my app.

Is there any way to get this method (from support library?) or to request a cellular network scan in any other way, or at least be informed when Android does a scan on its own?

Answer (score -1):

**Edit**: Unfortunately, this only *seems* to work, but there are not all the new methods in the support library. I'll leave the answer here nontheless, perhaps it helps anyone solving other problems.

To use support library:

Add the line

- `compileSdkVersion 28` in the `android` block
- `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'` in the `dependencies` block

to the module's `build.gradle`.

If Android Studio cannot find that library, add `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }` into the `repositories` block of the project's `build.gradle`.